# unexpected type error after terraform 0.12 migration

Tags: module, terraform

I am in the process of migrating my terraform 0.11 configuration to terraform 0.12.5.

The migration (using 0.12upgrade) went relatively smoothly, but then I encountered this error during the next plan

```
Error: Invalid value for module argument

  on main.tf line 72, in module "foo":
  72:   subnet_ids  = module.vpc.subnet_ids

The given value is not suitable for child module variable "subnet_ids"
defined at ../../modules/foo/main.tf:10,1-30: element 0: string
required.
```

The module `foo` has a (migrated) variable declaration subnet_ids that looks like this:

```
variable "subnet_ids" {
  type = list(string)
}
```

while the `vpc` module has an output declaration that is declared like this:

```
output "subnet_ids" {
  value = [aws_subnet.private.*.id]
}
```

<strike>It seems that if I relax the type constraint on the `foo` module the error goes away.</strike>

However, is this the correct thing to do. After all, isn't the output of the vpc module actually a list of strings? How do I check the type of the vpc output variable?

**Update:** relaxing the type constraint allows the first part of the validation to succeed, but merely causes problems for the consuming module when the variable is applied as per this output

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on ../../modules/foo/main.tf line 350, in resource "aws_ecs_service" "api":
 350: subnets         = var.subnet_ids

Inappropriate value for attribute "subnets": incorrect set element type:
string required.
```

So the question is: what am I doing wrong when I am defining the output value? How to I ensure the output value is a list of strings so that I don't get the original error? How can I inspect the type of `vpc.subnet_ids`?

Answer (score 5):

Turns out, I needed to change this:

```
output "subnet_ids" {
  value = [aws_subnet.private.*.id]
}
```

to this:

```
output "subnet_ids" {
  value = aws_subnet.private[*].id
}
```

Comment: `aws_subnet.private.*.id` would've worked too... the important thing is that `.*.id` already returns a list, so extra brackets around makes a list of lists. Unfortunately in this case the output value created an indirection that made the error show up somewhere far away from the cause.

Comment: @MartinAtkins Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

If you have list of `subnet_ids` you need to add like below

```
subnet_ids = flatten([module.vpc.public_subnets, module.vpc.private_subnets])
```

Check this [answer](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-vpc/issues/271#issuecomment-496853247) as well

Answer (score 0):

In the variable files mention the "subnet_ids" as a list.

```
variable "subnet_ids" {
  type = list
  default = []
}
```

Then in your module grab the subnet list as following

```
subnet_ids = [var.subnet_ids[0], var.subnet_ids[1]]
```